# UEFI stuck while backing up

Tags: backup, motherboard, uefi

I use ASROCK x99 extreme 6. I noticed that my uefi was outdated, so before updating it, I tried to take a backup. I used a function called "secure backup UEFI (A->B)", and now, the uefi is stuck with progress bar at 0. I see a red close button, but since there is no mouse cursor on the screen, I can't click it. What can I do? Is there a way to make this work, or cancel the backup?

EDIT: on the screen, it says "do not turn off while updating uefi".

EDIT2: after following the advice in the comments and turning it off, now I can't turn it on. Monitor doesn't turn on. Keyboard doesn't turn on. Have I bricked my pc?

Comment: You should be able to use TAB to get to that button. If not, just reboot.

Comment: Can I reboot though? It said "do not turn off while updating uefi".

Comment: If what you were doing was a backup copy (not the actual update), rebooting should not cause any harm. Probably it's stuck at 0 because the destination location is not accessible/write-able.

Comment: Alright. I'll try. If I succeed, you can post it as an answer. I'll mark it.

Comment: Oh no. I can't turn it back on

Comment: Do a reset of the BIOS, it probably tries to load from the backup. There absolutely no reason for the original image to be affected in any way.

Comment: CMOS clear fixed it